# Client proxy generation with Restlet for Java SE

Tags: java, wcf, odata, restlet

I'm trying to generate the client proxy code for a WCF service, using Restlet 2.0.4 (I tried also with the latest stable version, same result) as written here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/uruit/archive/2011/09/13/accessing-odata-from-android-using-restlet.aspx
The process fails with "SEVERE: Can't get the metadata for  (response's status: Bad Request (400) - Bad Request)"
I was figuring out what could be the problem with the Web Service, until I discovered, debugging in Eclipse, that the causa can be a ClassNotFoundException: seems it can't find the org.restlet.ext.odata.Service class (it crashes when Restlet tryies to do "Service service = new Service(...)" (org.restlet.ext.odata.Generator class, line 240), but it's in the Classpath.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Add the full stacktrace to your question please.

Comment: I'd like to do it, but I can't: Eclipse doesn't show me the complete stack trace. I tried to create a dummy web service, following this walkthrough: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668184.aspx and the code generation was successful. This means that the web service I'm trying to access has something wrong

Comment: Well, how is Eclipse 'crashing'? Does it silently fail? Does the IDE terminate? If an exception is being thrown you can trap it by wrapping your generator in a try/catch, then printing it out. Interesting tutorial by the way, I've picked up something new today (oData).

Comment: Is this a WCF service or an OData service (you might be confusing the two because of WCF Data Services, which is a stack that implements OData and has an unfortunate name)? It sounds to me like it's looking for $metadata and failing, which would of course not be present on a vanilla WCF service.

Comment: The problem was that my web service doesn't expose any metadata, but the configuration file says "expose metadata".

Comment: have you checked for more than one instance in the classpath?

Comment: the classpath was set by Eclipse whene I imported JAR files